# exception when initializing com.sun.jna.Structure in scala

Tags: scala, jna

I am trying to use JNA from scala. Basic stuff works, but I stumbled on using structures. I am trying to use localtime(time_t ts) function from libc, having defined following scala equivalent for struct tm as follows

```
class tm_struct (
  var wYear: Short = 0,
  var wMonth: Short = 0,
  var wDayOfWeek: Short = 0,
  var wDay: Short = 0,
  var wHour: Short = 0,
  var wMinute: Short = 0,
  var wSecond: Short = 0,
  var wMilliseconds: Short = 0) extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
  def getFieldOrder = List(Array("wYear", "wMonth", "wDayOfWeek", "wDay", "wHour", "wMinute", "wSecond", "wMilliseconds")).asJava
}
```

which compiles fine, but gives me a runtime error

```
[error] (run-main-8) java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

when trying to initialize new instance of class tm_struct. 
I would be grateful for any hints...

Comment: I think it's because you use a List of Arrays. If you use a List, however, another exception happens: java.lang.Error: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class tm_struct returns names ([wDay, wDayOfWeek, wHour, wMilliseconds, wMinute, wMonth, wSecond, wYear]) which do not match declared field names ([])

Comment: I should probably add that I have already tried using List, and gave up for the same error that you have mentioned... Either way I am stuck ...

Comment: I would guess that this has to do with the scala-specific support for JNA - perhaps that support is expecting a different JNA version?

Comment: Could be. Documentation for JNA in Scala is scarce, SNA is based on (I guess) some older JNA version, not the 4.1.0 that I am trying to use.

Comment: OK, folks from scala-users explained that to me - basically, in case class Scala compiler de-sugars parameters to private fields with accessor methods, whereas JNA expects public fields. So, the bottom line is that one cannot use JNA in Scala directly, at least for now

Comment: What about know ?